# Automate Tab Clicking and Submit

Tags: javascript, windows, shell

I have a tabbed form and a submit button on the form as shown in this image [image: Tabbed Form]

User has to click on all Tabs and then click submit button at the end. How can i automate this task

Answer (score 1):

Get tabs elements, and then execute its click method.

simple example：

```
document.getElementById('xxx').click()
```